# How to manage state transitions in python fsm using transitions library

Tags: python, transition, fsm

I am attempting to implement a state machine using the [transitions](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions) module.  Python version 2.7.13 and transitions is version 0.4.4.

In the project docs, the examples all advance through states by typing function calls on the command prompt.  Taking a snippet from the first example in the transitions docs, the state of `batman` is achieved by calling named functions `wake_up` and `work_out`

```
>>> batman.wake_up()
>>> batman.work_out()
>>> batman.state
'hungry'
```

I would like to have the state machine automatically advance through states conditioned on model data. The toy example below is what I am trying to do but relies on using a dummy function as a pointer to set the `next_state`.

Is there a way to do this that does not involve creating a `next_state` function and using it like a pointer?  The transition docs have an Ordered transition and conditional transitions But what I really want is to have conditional ordered transitions.

Is it possible to rewrite the code below without using a function pointer?

```
from transitions import Machine

class AModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sv = 0  # state variable of the model

    def on_enter_sA(self):
        print "Entered sA"
        self.next_state = self.to_sB

    def on_enter_sB(self):
        print "Entered sB"
        if self.sv < 3:
            self.next_state = self.to_sB
        else:
            self.next_state = self.to_sC

    def on_enter_sC(self):
        print "Entered sC"
        if self.sv == 6:
            self.next_state = self.to_sD

    def on_enter_sD(self):
        print "Entered sD"
        self.next_state = self.to_sA

    def next_state(self):
        pass

#setup model and state machine  
model = AModel()

#init transitions model
list_of_states = ['sA','sB','sC','sD']
transitions = [
    {'trigger':'to_sA','source':'sD','dest':'sA'},
    {'trigger':'to_sB','source':'sA','dest':'sB'},
    {'trigger':'to_sC','source':'sB','dest':'sC'},
    {'trigger':'to_sD','source':'sC','dest':'sD'}
]
machine = Machine(model=model, states=list_of_states, initial='sA', 
             transitions=transitions)

model.next_state = model.to_sB #init next state pointer

#begin main
for i in range(0,8):
    print 'iter is: ' + str(i) + " -model state is:" +  model.state
    model.sv = i #update model state variable, local state logic
                 #will determine what next_state points to
    model.next_state()
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with function pointers?

Comment: In general nothing.  The transitions library seems to be so nice that using pointers the way I was doing looked a clumsy compared to the examples.  If I was doing this in C, function pointers would be totally natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature has been requested before (see [this issue](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions/issues/138)). As you can also see, there is someone working on it. He might open a pull request in the near future. I have not reviewed his changes but will surely do when this happens.

For now, you can let your model handle the condition checks and combine this with ordered transitions to get rid of the need to frequently update the `next_state` function pointer. Since you are just checking an index this could look like this:

```
from transitions import Machine


class AModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sv = 0  # state variable of the model
        self.conditions = {  # each state 
            'sA': 0,
            'sB': 3,
            'sC': 6,
            'sD': 0,
        }

    def poll(self):
        if self.sv >= self.conditions[self.state]:
            self.next_state()


# setup model and state machine
model = AModel()

# init transitions model
list_of_states = ['sA', 'sB', 'sC', 'sD']
machine = Machine(model=model, states=list_of_states, initial='sA', ordered_transitions=True)

# begin main
for i in range(0, 10):
    print('iter is: ' + str(i) + " -model state is:" +  model.state)
    model.sv = i
    model.poll()
```

I assumed that you poll the model every time the index is increased. If this is the case `self.sv == 6` and `self.sv >= 6` do the same thing (for `sC` to `sD`).
However, if the operator was intentional chosen you can change the model condition check to use an operator value tuple:

```
from transitions import Machine
import operator


class AModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sv = 0  # state variable of the model
        self.conditions = {  # each state
            'sA': (operator.ne, None),
            'sB': (operator.ge, 3),
            'sC': (operator.eq, 6),
            'sD': (operator.ne, None),
        }

    def poll(self):
        op, value = self.conditions[self.state]
        if op(self.sv, value):
            self.next_state()


# setup model and state machine
model = AModel()

# init transitions model
list_of_states = ['sA', 'sB', 'sC', 'sD']
machine = Machine(model=model, states=list_of_states, initial='sA', ordered_transitions=True)

# begin main
for i in range(0, 10):
    print('iter is: ' + str(i) + " -model state is:" + model.state)
    model.sv = i
    model.poll()
```

In both cases, the output is:

```
iter is: 0 -model state is:sA
iter is: 1 -model state is:sB
iter is: 2 -model state is:sB
iter is: 3 -model state is:sB
iter is: 4 -model state is:sC
iter is: 5 -model state is:sC
iter is: 6 -model state is:sC
iter is: 7 -model state is:sD
iter is: 8 -model state is:sA
iter is: 9 -model state is:sB
```

But again, I assumed something which might be wrong: I assumed that changing states if the condition is fulfilled is sufficient. This is how conditions would work. But maybe you actually intend to exit and enter states every time you poll your model. In this case you can use `auto_transitions` and retrieve them dynamically with `getattr`:

```
from transitions import Machine


class AModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sv = 0  # state variable of the model
        self.conditions = {  # each state
            'sA': 0,
            'sB': 3,
            'sC': 6,
            'sD': 0,
        }

    def poll(self):
        if self.sv >= self.conditions[self.state]:
            self.next_state()  # go to next state
        else:
            getattr(self, 'to_%s' % self.state)()  # enter current state again

    def on_enter(self):
        print('entered state %s' % self.state)

    def on_exit(self):
        print('exited state %s' % self.state)


# setup model and state machine
model = AModel()

# init transitions model
list_of_states = ['sA', 'sB', 'sC', 'sD']
machine = Machine(model=model, states=list_of_states, initial='sA',
                  ordered_transitions=True, before_state_change='on_exit',
                  after_state_change='on_enter')

# begin main
for i in range(0, 10):
    print('iter is: ' + str(i) + " -model state is:" +  model.state)
    model.sv = i
    model.poll()
```

For the sake of simplicity, I added functions that print messages every time a state is entered or exited. This is not required if you use a logger since `transitions` logs these events as well.

Comment: Great response!  I appreciate how you show multiple approaches using ordered transitions.  This looks very clean, very clear examples.  Thanks

Comment: Tried to vote your response up but my rep is too low for it to be publicly visible..

Comment: @Matt: no worries. Glad I could help. I wish you all the best for your project!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out how to add this to the transitions module, however I whipped this up to automatically transition based on conditions:

```
class StateMachine:
    def __init__(self, name, states, transitions, initialState):
        self.name=name
        self.states=set()
        self.transitions=set()
        self.state=None

        for s in states:
            _s=State(s)
            self.states.add(_s)
            if self.state==None:
                self.state=_s
            elif s==initialState:
                self.state=_s

        for t in transitions:
            # self.addTransition(t)

    def addTransition(self, transition):
        name=transition[0]
        for s in self.states:
            #fromState
            if s.name==transition[1]:
                fromState=s
            #toState
            elif s.name==transition[2]:
                toState=s
        #condition
        condition=getattr(self, transition[3])
        #action     
        if len(transition)==5:
            action = getattr(self, transition[4])()
        else:
            action=self.passAction
        t=Transition(name, fromState, toState, condition, action)
        fromState.transitions.add(t)

    def passAction(self):
        print('pass!!!')

    def run(self):
        self.state=self.state.testTransitions()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name+':'+str(self.states)

class State:
    def __init__(self, name='state'):
        self.name=name
        self.transitions=set()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name+':'+str(self.transitions)

    def testTransitions(self):
        state=self
        for t in self.transitions:
            if t.condition() is True:
                t.action()
                state=t.toState
        return state

class Transition:
    def __init__(self, name, fromState, toState, condition, action): 
        self.name=name
        self.fromState=fromState
        self.toState=toState
        self.condition=condition
        self.action=action

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class TestSM(StateMachine):
    def __init__(self, name, states, transitions, initialState):
        StateMachine.__init__(self, name, states, transitions, initialState)

    def testCondition(self):
        print('testCondition!!!')
        return True



states=['a', 'b', 'c']
transitions=[
    ['aTOb', 'a', 'b', 'testCondition'],
    ['bTOc', 'b', 'c', 'testCondition'],
    ['cTOa', 'c', 'a', 'testCondition'],
    ]
sm=TestSM('testSM', states, transitions, 'a')

for s in sm.states:
    print(s.name)

print('fin')
```

In order to run the state machine, simply run the 'run' function, eg:

```
sm.run()
```